# Расширение Yii2 EAuth. Проблема с авторизацией через вКонтакт из-за вида ссылок

Tags: yii2, oauth2

Заинтересовался авторизацией через соцсети в Yii2, набрел на этот проект: http://nodge.ru/yii-eauth/demo2/
По этой ссылке в нём прекрасно логинится через вКонтакт)

Скачал его к себе на комп из репозитория https://github.com/Nodge/yii2-eauth-demo/ и начал экспериментировать на локальном сервере XAMPP. Намучавшись с конфигурированием Апача (сделал virtual host для адреса вида yii2vk.com) и некоторыми другими проблемами, упёрся в то что с локалхоста не авторизует с кнопки VK со страницы логина из-за того, что ссылки авторизации имеют извращенный вид типа http://yii2vk.com/login?service=vkontakte - в то время как на исходном демо-сайте они имели нормальный вид типа http://nodge.ru/yii-eauth/demo2/login/vkontakte

И вообще ссылки со всех соцкнопок на локалхосте имеют вид login?service=...

При этом если напрямую вбить в адресной строке http://yii2vk.com/login/vkontakte - то всё прекрасно авторизуется, даже несмотря на то что локалхост))) не работают именно кнопки из-за странных ссылок из них.

С ЧПУ вроде бы нормально всё, иначе бы http://yii2vk.com/login выдавало бы 404-ю (как оно в самом начале и выдавало, пока я не сконфигурировал Апач корректно, чтобы не надо было вбивать index.php?r=site/login).

В чём может быть дело? Почему на демо-сайте ссылки с соцкнопок со страницы логина правильные, а у меня криво всё?

Comment: Ссылки такого вида из-за некорректного чпу, смотрели как настраивать компонент? Не авторизирует, на локалке может из-за , некоторые сервисы проверяют доступность адреса, если ваш локальный сайт не видно из интернета, то не пустит, вторая причина - некорректные настройки приложения в соц сетях.

Comment: На локалке прекрасно авторизует, если вместо ссылки выдаваемой кнопкой вбить в браузер http://yii2vk.com/login/vkontakte - и это же говорит, что моё приложение понимает именно ЧПУ формат. Проблема в том, что соц.кнопки почему-то ссылку выдают неправильного вида.

Саму демку я скачал с уже проведенными настройками ЧПУ (в репозитории же то же самое, что и на демо-сайте где с этим ОК всё).
В папке /web лежит файл .htaccess с соответствующими настройками, а в конфиге включены prettyUrl.

Comment: Хотя уже и у меня чувство, что ЧПУ не до конца настроено. Если вернуться к полностью не-ЧПУ-шному виду ссылки с кнопки, временно вырубив prettyUrl в /config/web.php она будет выглядеть как http://yii2vk.com/index.php?r=site/login&service=vkontakte

И проблема в том, как в правилах urlManager загнать в совсем ЧПУ-вид хвостик "&service=vkontakte". Читаю документацию, не могу понять.

Comment: Дело в том что вид ссылок не должен влиять на авторизацию, точнее там уже как приложение настроено. Вы пробовали правило для urlManager которое написано в документации ? `'login/<service:google|facebook|etc>' => 'site/login',`